# Problems with installing ssl package in python 2.5

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ssl

I noticed I have this warning:

`WARNING  2011-05-07 00:50:51,371 urlfetch_stub.py:106] No ssl package found. urlfetch will not be able to validate SSL certificates.`

So I downloaded the ssl 1.15 library.

Tried to install using setup.py and got this:

`error: package directory 'ssl' does not exist`

Update:

I added python to the path, now I'm getting a new error, something about visual studio 2003, and having to use MingW32. Adding `-cmingw32` parameter doesn't work (option m is not recognised).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying python 26 on my computer, the only conclusion is that I'm experiencing this bug:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4824&q=ssl&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

(because python 26 is supposed to have ssl built in)

Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to install this by using pip. It's very easy, just go to a terminal and type, `pip install ssl`, which will automatically install the SSL module. You may need root privileges, however.

Comment: I don't have pip installed, when I try to install it I get the same error - directory does not exist

Comment: Ok I added python to windows environment variables path. Now I managed to install pip, but I don't know how to get to terminal. Is it just command line or what?

Comment: Ah, you're on windows. Yes, the terminal is the command line.